# What methods, technologies, or services simplify making donations on mobile devices?

Tags: iphone, mobile, paypal

We are producing a website catered specifically to mobile devices and we need to accept donations. We would like to make this process as quick, easy, and convenient for mobile devices as possible. We are open to using any payment gateway (i.e. Paypal, Authorize.net, NMI, etc.).

My employer feels that having someone enter billing information from their mobile device is too inconvenient, but limiting ourselves to only donations from, for example, Paypal members would be unwise. We are trying to find a way to maximize viewers who can donate (as close to everybody as we can get), but also make the experience simpler than having to enter their billing information into a mobile device.

I have considered apps that store prerecorded billing information and Bump Pay. Are there any other effective middle grounds or solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

I would think a simple middle ground is to use a credit card platform and not ask for billing information. Many mobile apps do not ask for it. Authorize.net and other gateways can be configured to not require it. Simply ask for zip code. Or ask for no address info at all. Since you are not shipping an actual product (coming out of pocket for goods), if there is a fraud chargeback it's not really that big a deal. And I can't imagine a lot of credit card thieves are going to burn stolen credit cards to make charitable donations.

Answer (score 0):

Tanoro - Not sure what you are asking is possible.  If you want to accept the widest range of payment methods, you need to have a lowest denominator solution.  In this case, that means accepting cards directly (by allowing billing information directly).  If you do end up accepting payment info directly, check out Braintree and their iOS client library: https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/ios